# Python Selenium TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'WebElement' objects

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am using Python with Selenium Webdriver
I have got the value of a textfield which is 1,000.000
I am using an if statement to check if the value from the textfield = 1,000.000
If Yes then pass else i use send_keys and enter 1,000.000 into the text field.

I am getting the following error:
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'WebElement' objects

```
Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Webdriver\reverted to backup\ClearCore 501\TestCases\DataPreviewsPage_TestCase.py", line 93, in test_add_DataPreviews
dp.is_maxrecords_1000_displayed()
File "C:\Webdriver\reverted to backup\ClearCore 501\Pages\data_previews.py", line 76, in is_maxrecords_1000_displayed
print "max_records_textfield does not have default value 1,000.00 The value  is = " + max_records_textfield
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'WebElement' objects
```

My code snippet is:

## max records textfield has the value 1,000.000 as default

```
    def is_maxrecords_1000_displayed(self):
        max_records_textfield = self.driver.find_element(*MainPageLocators.datapreviews_maxrecords_textfield2)
        print "max_records_textfield = ",  max_records_textfield.get_attribute('value')
        if max_records_textfield.get_attribute('value') == "1,000.000":
            print "max_records_textfield" + max_records_textfield.get_attribute('value')
        else:
            print "max_records_textfield does not have default value 1,000.00 The value is = " + max_records_textfield
            print "Going to enter 1,000.00 into the textfield"
            max_records_textfield.send_keys("1,000.00")
```

Do i need to cast the webelement (max_records_textfield) to a string variable?
How would i do this?

Comment: Use - `max_records_textfield.get_attribute('value')` , instead of the `WebElement` - `print "max_records_textfield does not have default value 1,000.00 The value is = " + max_records_textfield.get_attribute('value')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Error message is very clear, You are trying to concatenate string with a `WebElement` object.

If you want to print its value use - `max_records_textfield.get_attribute('value')` (Just as you used in the if condition and the print statement inside the `if` block) -

```
print "max_records_textfield does not have default value 1,000.00 The value is = " + max_records_textfield.get_attribute('value')
```

Comment: Ah i forgot the .get_attribute('value') at the end.  It's working now.  Thanks.